# Racket is a define form in a procedure run multiple times?

Tags: recursion, optimization, racket

In Racket it is possible to define a procedure and constants inside of another procedure, for example like this:

```
(define (a a-list)
  (define something 10)
  (display a-list)
  (cond
    [(empty? a-list) (display "done")]
    [else
      (display a-list) (newline)
      (a (rest a-list))]))
```

Printing the list and then taking away the first element, then printing the list again and so on until the list is empty.

In the example procedure a value `something` is defined to be `10`, for whatever reason. When the procedure recurses, does Racket define the value again, or is it intelligent enough to notice, that this definition does not change?

Also it would probably be on the stack space of the previously called procedure, if this is not optimized and it would consume some more memory per recursive step, depending on what `something` is defined as. For example lets say a million numbers in a list, but never changing numbers. Obviously if things inside that definition depend on the list given as parameter, it cannot so simply be optimized.

If this is not optimized, is it a good idea to not have too many `define` forms inside a recursive function, or only the ones, which consume little space? Putting them outside of the procedures would make them accessible from other procedures though, even if only the one procedure ever uses them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `define` expression *is* evaluated every time the procedure is invoked. Consider this example:

```
(define (test1)
  (define x (begin (display "Hello from test1 ") 10))
  x)

(test1)
=> Hello from test1 10
(test1)
=> Hello from test1 10
(test1)
=> Hello from test1 10
```

If you want a value inside a procedure to be evaluated only once (when the procedure itself is created), you can put it in a scope outside the procedure, it'll still be accessible because a `lambda` defines a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) over its lexical environment:

```
(define test2
  (let ((x (begin (display "Hello from test2") 20)))
    (lambda () x)))

=> Hello from test2
(test2)
=> 20
(test2)
=> 20
(test2)
=> 20
```

Comment: I don't understand the first example. Of course when I call the procedure it will print that value of `x`. I am rather wondering, if there is optimization going on behind the scenes to avoid having to define the value of `x` every single time, because it is the same every time.

The advice about how to do it with a closure seems to be great though, in case there is no such optimization for unchanging definitions in procedures (and maybe also in general?).

Maybe I should have asked something like _"Does the JIT of Racket optimize definitions of unchanging values in procedures?"_

Comment: You don't get it - yeah, it prints `x`, but it _also prints the value in the `display` part_, every time. Defines have to be evaluated every time, that's non-optimizable.

Comment: Ah now I get it! Thanks! What I don't understand is, why it would be completely unoptimizable regardless what kind of definition it is. I mean something like `(define a 10)` and other unchanging definition of values. 

So I guess it would be a good practice to use the way you used in the second example, to avoid evaluating multiple times the same unchanging thing?

Comment: The expression that gets bound to the value inside a `define` could change every time the procedure is executed, or the variable itself could be modified or reassigned inside the procedure, so the compiler has no other choice but to evaluate it every time. So yes, if you need an expression to be evaluated only once, do it as we did above in the second example.

Comment: Do you know a website or other source, which lists something like best practices in Racket, which include things like your second example, with explanation such as you've given? I'd like to learn Racket "the right way" from the start.

Comment: IMHO the best book in town for learning Scheme is "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs". I don't know of such a book specifically for Racket. Also see "The little Schemer", and "How to Design Programs".